# Is there a way to stop a villager turning into a witch after being struck by lightning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a vanilla server and need a villager to be struck by lightning, but every time I run the command (as expected) the villager turns into a witch. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Why do you need the villager to get hit by lightining?

Comment: because I'm making the /lightning plugin, and need a villager to be near you when you run it

Comment: @Command Helper5000 If your question is related to mod development it would be better placed in gamedev.stackexchange.com where you would get a more fitting answer to your question.

Comment: @Grirg If he's trying to do this using the built-in Minecraft commands, this question is perfectly on-topic for Arqade. In fact, I think it would be considered off-topic if posted at GameDev.

Comment: @MageXy You are right, I should have supposed it's might be done with command blocks. Obviously to publish it on Game Dev he would need to adjust the format and the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just summon the lightning one block above the villager using relative coordinates? example: /execute @e[type=Villager] ~ ~ ~ summon LightningBolt ~ ~+1 ~